# How to read stdout (UTF-8) from executable in PowerShell as string?

Tags: powershell, unicode, powershell-core

I have a native executable (`my.exe`) that outputs raw UTF-8 including emoji.

If I execute it and attempt to save STDOUT as a string `$a = my.exe` the variable `$a` contains garbled text - I assume because PowerShell if working with UTF-16 natively.

Is it possible to get the output from the executable properly decoded from UTF-8 to the native PowerShell encoding into a string?

Comment: Look into the following: `[Console]::InputEncoding`, `[Console]::OutputEncoding` and the `$OutputEncoding` automatic variable.

Comment: Is it possible to post a small C# example?